# what's wrong with the "cout&endl" and the "boost"?

Tags: c++, boost

This is the first time I use the boost on my machine - Ubuntu 12.04 amd64(with g++ 4.6.3).
Below is the source:

```
#include <boost/timer.hpp>

using namespace boost;

int main()
{
  timer t;

  cout << "max timespan: "
       << t.elapsed_max() / 3600 << "h" << endl;

  cout << "min timespan: "
       << t.elapsed_min() << "s" << endl;

  cout << "now time elapsed:"
       << t.elapsed() << "s" << endl;

  return 0;
```

}

However, when i compile it with `g++ timer_test.c -o timer_test`, the strange error appear:

```
timer_test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
timer_test.cpp:9:3: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
timer_test.cpp:10:44: error: ‘endl’ was not declared in this scope
```

Then I tried alter the `cout` and `endl` to `std::cout` and `std::endl`, the error become:

```
error: ‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’
error: ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

Comment: Where are `std::cout` and `std::endl` declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to include `iostream` header and use `std::cout and std::endl` as they are defined in `std` namespace.

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << "max timespan: "
   << t.elapsed_max() / 3600 << "h" << std::endl;
```

and same to other `cout`, `endl`

Answer (score 1):

Bung in `#include <iostream>` at the top of the file.

Basic stuff really

Comment: along with std::cout etc